# is transaction can be cancelled after event raise on binance smart chain or Ethereum?

Tags: solidity, web3js

I am creating backend which monitor events on BSC and make cross chain tx.

but I heard that transaction can be replace or cancelled before confirmed.

so in my case does anyone make tx -> event get raised -> cross chain processed -> revert/cancel tx before confirm?

Comment: If the event got raised/emited. Your transaction has been mined.And can't be cancelled.
You would need to replace it ASAP with Lot's of gas and even then there is no guaranty that your second transaction with the same nonce will get picked up before the previous  one.

Comment: does replacement allow to change amount?

Comment: Yes. But it will only work if you provided enough gas so it gets picked up first.

Comment: so there is possibility of fraud happen after backend processing unconfirmed event.

Comment: Not really. The second transaction still need to be sent and signed.